# jQuery Mobile with x3dom diffuseColor control

Tags: javascript, jquery, x3dom

I followed an example code and ended up with a not working application. I checked and checked again and it 'should' work all right, however it doesn't. So I am asking you if you could pinpoint where did I go wrong :/

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Web3D</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/css.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/css.min.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.x3dom.org/download/dev/x3dom.css"></link>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.x3dom.org/download/dev/x3dom.js"></script> 
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/colorScript.js"></script>
       <style>
            label { width: 100px; float: left; clear: both; }
            #ctrlContainer { border: 1px solid #000; padding: 20px; float: left; width: 280px; margin-left: 20px; }
            #sliderContainer div { float:left; width: 200px; }
            #sliderContainer li { height: 25px; }
            #sliderContainer ul { clear: both; list-style-type: none; margin: 20px 0 10px 0; padding: 0; }
       </style>

    </head>

    <body>

<!-- PAGE 1 --> 
        <div data-role="page" id="first" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Something Rotating | Homework 1</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->  
            <!-- NAVIGATION -->    
            <div data-role="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#first" data-transition="flip" data-icon="info">Something Rotating</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#second" data-transition="flip" data-icon="user">Controlling Objects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#third" data-transition="flip" data-icon="location">Inline Importing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div><!-- /header -->
<!-- /NAVIGATION -->       

            <div data-role="content">
            <x3d width="500px" height="400px">
    <scene>
        <transform id="objectToAnimate">
            <shape>
                <appearance>
                    <material diffuseColor='red'></material>
                    <imageTexture url='textures/bamboo.jpg'></imageTexture>
                </appearance>

                <box/>
            </shape>
        </transform>

    <timeSensor id="time" loop="true" cycleInterval="4"/>
    <orientationInterpolator id="objectAnimatation" key="0 0.5 1" keyValue="0 1 0 0  0 1 0 1.57079  0 1 0 3.14159  0 1 0 4.71239  0 1 0 6.28317"></orientationInterpolator>

    <ROUTE fromNode='time' fromField='fraction_changed' toNode='objectAnimatation' toField='set_fraction'></ROUTE>
    <ROUTE fromNode='objectAnimatation' fromField='value_changed' toNode='objectToAnimate' toField='set_rotation'></ROUTE>

    </scene>
</x3d>  
            </div><!-- /content -->
            <!-- CONTENT --> 
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h4>This is the footer</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->
<!-- /CONTENT -->  

        </div><!-- /page -->
<!-- /PAGE 1 -->

<!-- PAGE 2 --> 
        <div data-role="page" id="second" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"  data-add-back-btn="true">
                <h1>Controlling Objects | Homework 2</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->  
            <!-- NAVIGATION -->    
            <div data-role="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#first" data-transition="flip" data-icon="info">Something Rotating</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#second" data-transition="flip" data-icon="user">Controlling Objects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#third" data-transition="flip" data-icon="location">Inline Importing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div><!-- /header -->
<!-- /NAVIGATION -->       

            <div data-role="content">
            <h2>Change the color of the cube using the RGB sliders, which updates the "diffuseColor" attribute of the Material node using jQuery.</h2>
<!--SCENE STARTS-->
<x3d xmlns="http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-namespace" id="spheres" showStat="true" x="0px" y="0px" width="400px" height="400px" style="float:left;">
    <scene DEF='scene'>
        <transform id="objectToAnimate">
            <shape>
                <appearance>
                    <material diffuseColor='0 0 0' specularColor='.2 .2 .2'></material>
                </appearance>

                <box DEF='box'/>
            </shape>
        </transform>

    <timeSensor id="time" loop="true" cycleInterval="4"/>
    <orientationInterpolator id="objectAnimatation" key="0 0.5 1" keyValue="0 1 0 0, 0 1 0 3, 0 1 0 6"></orientationInterpolator>

    <ROUTE fromNode='time' fromField='fraction_changed' toNode='objectAnimatation' toField='set_fraction'></ROUTE>
    <ROUTE fromNode='objectAnimatation' fromField='value_changed' toNode='objectToAnimate' toField='set_rotation'></ROUTE>

    </scene>
</x3d>
<!--/SCENE ENDS-->
<!--CONTROLLER STARTS-->
   <div id="ctrlContainer">
        <div id="sliderContainer">
            <ul>
                <li><label>Red</label><div id="redSlider" class="slider"/></li>
                <li><label>Green</label><div id="greenSlider" class="slider"/></li>
                <li><label>Blue</label><div id="blueSlider" class="slider"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--/CONTROLLER ENDS-->  
            </div><!-- /content -->
            <!-- CONTENT --> 
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h4>This is the footer</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->
<!-- /CONTENT -->  

        </div><!-- /page -->
<!-- /PAGE 2 -->

<!-- PAGE 3 --> 
        <div data-role="page" id="third" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"  data-add-back-btn="true">
                <h1>Inline Importing | Homework 3</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->  
            <!-- NAVIGATION -->    
            <div data-role="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#first" data-transition="flip" data-icon="info">Something Rotating</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#second" data-transition="flip" data-icon="user">Controlling Objects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#third" data-transition="flip" data-icon="location">Inline Importing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div><!-- /header -->
<!-- /NAVIGATION -->       

            <div data-role="content">
            <h2>Change the color of the cube using the RGB sliders, which updates the "diffuseColor" attribute of the Material node using jQuery.</h2>
<!--SCENE STARTS-->
<x3d xmlns="http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-namespace" id="spheres" showStat="true" x="0px" y="0px" width="400px" height="400px" style="float:left;">
    <scene DEF='scene'>
        <transform id="objectToAnimate">
            <shape>
                <appearance>
                    <material diffuseColor='0 0 0' specularColor='.2 .2 .2'></material>
                </appearance>

                <box DEF='box'/>
            </shape>
        </transform>

    <timeSensor id="time" loop="true" cycleInterval="4"/>
    <orientationInterpolator id="objectAnimatation" key="0 0.5 1" keyValue="0 1 0 0, 0 1 0 3, 0 1 0 6"></orientationInterpolator>

    <ROUTE fromNode='time' fromField='fraction_changed' toNode='objectAnimatation' toField='set_fraction'></ROUTE>
    <ROUTE fromNode='objectAnimatation' fromField='value_changed' toNode='objectToAnimate' toField='set_rotation'></ROUTE>

    </scene>
</x3d>
<!--/SCENE ENDS-->
<!--CONTROLLER STARTS-->
   <div id="ctrlContainer">
        <div id="sliderContainer">
            <ul>
                <li><label>Red</label><div id="redSlider" class="slider"/></li>
                <li><label>Green</label><div id="greenSlider" class="slider"/></li>
                <li><label>Blue</label><div id="blueSlider" class="slider"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--/CONTROLLER ENDS-->  
            </div><!-- /content -->
            <!-- CONTENT --> 
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h4>This is the footer</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->
<!-- /CONTENT -->  

        </div><!-- /page -->
<!-- /PAGE 3 -->

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the content of 'js/colorScript.js' that is linked in the header:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    // Create the sliders
    $(".slider").slider({min: 0, max: 1, step: 0.01, slide: function(e, ui) {
        var newCol =   $("#redSlider").slider('option', 'value') + " " 
                     + $("#greenSlider").slider('option', 'value') + " "  
                     + $("#blueSlider").slider('option', 'value');              
        $("Material").attr("diffuseColor", newCol);
    }});
});
```

It should work, however it doesn't...

Comment: How ever it doesn't? What should we take from that expression? What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error message? I don't know much about jQuery, but $("Material") might not be working if you have several material nodes (e.g. it might be case sensitive and maybe you want the first or last within that array of nodes).

Comment: Well, it displays all right, and the sliders also work, but do nothing. I mean they do not modify the diffuseColor. But thanks for the tip, so obvious, I actually did not think of case sensibility... :D

Comment: Here's a link to the (not properly working) app: http://users.metropolia.fi/~nicolaed/A_x3d/#second

Comment: Some remarks: Even though you take care of the case now, you missed, that there are more than one "Material" node. Second there is no event fired after changing the value of the sliders. Third those sliders have NaN as value. Finally: $("#blueSlider").slider('option', 'value') (and the others) give null, probably because of #3.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes I noticed that there are more than one material tags, and solved that, but it still didn't work. The code itself should be correct, I copied it from a working application: http://localhost/A_x3d/js/colorScript.js